# Questions about anonymous mapped memory in linux

Tags: c, linux, memory-mapped-files, memoization

I'm playing around with the idea of using the virtual memory system to allow me to do transparent data conversion (eg int to float) for some numeric data stuff I've got.  The basic idea is that the library I'm writing mmaps the data file you want, and at the same time mmaps an anonymous region of an appropriate size to hold the converted data, and this pointer is returned to the user.

The anonymous region is read/write protected, so that whenever the user goes to access data through the pointer, every new page will cause a segfault, which I can catch, then transparently convert data from the mmaped file and fix up the permissions allowing the access to continue.  This part of the whole thing works great so far.

However, sometimes I mmap very large files (hundreds of gigabytes), and with the anonymous memory proxying access to it, pretty quickly you'll start eating swap space as anonymous pages are dropped to disk.  My thought was that if I could explicitly set the dirty bit on the anonymous pages to false after writing converted data to them, the OS would just drop them and zero-fill on demand later if they were re-accessed.

For this to work though, I think I'd have to set the dirty bit to false *and* convince the OS to set pages to be read protected when they're swapped out, so I can re-catch the ensuing segfault and reconvert the data on demand.  After doing some research I don't think this is possible without kernel hacking, but I thought I'd ask and see if someone that knows more about the virtual memory system knows a way this might be achieved.

Comment: TBH, if your plan involves a library catching SIGSEGV, you're doing something horrible to folks who are going to use said library. Why don't you just have a "this float is not yet converted" value (e.g., negative 0) that you can test to see if the conversion's already been made?

Comment: Sorry I say "library" but this is really just a header for use by myself and a few other close co-workers, not for general consumption.  And there's more type conversions to be done than just int -> float, that's just an example.

Comment: I'm still going to raise objections based on the "sounds like an overly-complex way to do something conceptually simple" principle, but it's your time spent developing/debugging, so go wild.

Comment: Sure it's conceptually simple, but being able to access data through a pointer has a _lot_ of benefits when it comes to code clarity in the actual applications I want to write.  No bufferology or reading/writing required.

Comment: A better solution might be to write a FUSE filesystem that presents the converted data as a file - your end application can then just `mmap()` that file, and your FUSE filesystem will be called when the mmap region is accessed to create the file contents on-demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea (completely untested though): for the converted data, `mmap` and `munmap` individual pages as you need them.  Since the pages are backed by anonymous memory they should be discarded when they are unmapped.  Linux will coalesce adjacent mappings into a single VMA, so this might have acceptable overhead.

Of course, there needs to be a mechanism to trigger the unmapping.  You could maintain an LRU structure and evict an older page when you need to bring a new one in, thus keeping the size of the mapped region constant.

Comment: That's an idea.... I could modify my sigsegv handler to do an munmap/mmap to keep a constant size of memory in-use.  Do you think mremap would be sufficient, or whould I have to re-mmap the pages with a fixed address?

Comment: The new page would have to be mapped at the address causing the fault (since the user will expect it there).  I'd just `mmap` anonymous memory with `MAP_FIXED` to get this effect.  `mremap` might make it harder to remove a page in the middle of a range.  I think the performance will be mostly affected by touching the page table, and both `mmap` and `mremap` would have to do it; it'll be slow either way.

Comment: @tbert [This is possible on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675040/does-linux-allow-any-system-call-to-be-made-from-signal-handlers), but is definitely not portable.

Comment: @gct Actually, you might have to use both `mmap` and `mremap` to stay safe in a multithreaded program.  First you'd mmap a page into a temporary address, fill it, and remap to the correct location.  Otherwise a different thread might see a partially filled page, since [SIGSEGV can be thread-directed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533373/is-sigsegv-delivered-to-each-thread).

Comment: All great advice, this software's exclusively for linux so I'm OK if I have to play some non-portable games to get what I want, as long as it's ultimately safe non-portable stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Extending on a suggestion I mentioned in your earlier related question, I think the following (Linux-specific, definitely not portable) scheme should work quite reliably:

- Set up a datagram socket pair using `socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0, &sv)`,
  and signal handler for `SIGSEGV`. (You won't need to worry about `SIGBUS`, even if other processes might truncate the data file.)
- The signal handler uses `write()` to write the `size_t addr = siginfo->si_addr;` to its end of the socket. The signal handler then `read()`s one byte from the socket it wrote into (blocking -- this is basically just a reliable `sleep()` -- so remember to handle `EINTR`), and returns.

  Note that even if there are multiple threads faulting at or near the same time, there is no race condition. The signals just get reraised until the mappings are fixed.

  If there is any kind of a problem with the socket communications, you can use `sigaction()` with `.sa_handler = SIG_DFL` to restore the default `SIGSEGV` signal handler, so that when the same signal is reraised the entire process dies as normal.
- A separate thread reads the other end of the socket pair for addresses faulted with `SIGSEGV`, does all the mapping and file I/O necessary, and finally writes a zero byte to the same end of the socket pair to let the real signal handler know the mapping should be fixed now.

  This is basically the "real" signal handler, without the drawbacks of an actual signal handler. Remember, the same thread will keep reraising the same signal until the mapping is fixed, so any race conditions between the separate thread and `SIGSEGV` signals are irrelevant.
- Have one `PROT_NONE`, `MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_NORESERVE` mapping matching the size of the original data file.

  To reduce the cost in actual RAM -- using `MAP_NORESERVE` you use neither RAM nor SWAP for the mapping, but for gigabytes of data, the page table entries themselves require considerable RAM --, you could try using `MAP_HUGETLB` too. It would use huge pages, and therefore significantly less entries, but I am unsure whether there are issues when normal page sized holes are eventually punched into the mappings; you'd probably have to use huge pages all the way.

  This is the "full" mapping that your "userspace" will use to access the data.
- Have one `PROT_READ` or `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE`, `MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS` mapping for pristine or dirty (respectively), converted data. If your "userspace" almost always modifies the data, you can always treat the converted data as "dirty", but otherwise you can avoid unnecessary writes of unmodified data by first mapping the converted data `PROT_READ` only; if it faults, `mprotect()` it `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE` and mark it dirty (so needs to be converted and saved back to the file). I'll call these two stages "clean" and "dirty" mappings respectively.
- When the dedicated thread punches a hole into a "full" mapping for a "clean" page(s), you first `mmap(NULL, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, ...)` a new memory area of suitable size, `read()` the data from the desired data file into it, convert the data, `mprotect(..., PROT_READ)` if you separate "clean" and "dirty" mappings, and finally `mremap(newly_mapped, size, size, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, new_ptr)` it over the section of the "full" mapping.

  Note that to avoid any accidents, you should use a *global*  `pthread_mutex_t`, which is grabbed for the duration of these `mremap()`s and any `mmap()` calls elsewhere, to avoid having the kernel give the punched hole to the wrong thread by accident. The mutex will guard against any other thread getting in between. (Otherwise, the kernel might place a small map requested by another thread into the temporary hole.)
- When discarding "clean" page(s), you call `mmap(NULL, length, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0)` to get a new map of suitable length, then grab the global mutex mentioned above, and `mremap()` that new map over the "clean" page(s); the kernel does an implicit `munmap()`. Unlock the mutex.
- When discarding "dirty" page(s), you call `mmap(NULL, length, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0)` *twice to get *two* new maps of suitable length*. You then grab the global mutex mentioned above, and `mremap()` the dirty data over the first of the new mappings. (Basically it was only used to find out a suitable address to move the dirty data into.) Then, `mremap()` the second of the new mappings to where the dirty data used to reside in. Unlock the mutex.

---

Using a separate thread to handle the fault conditions avoids all async-signal-safe function problems. `read()`, `write()`, and `sigaction()` are all async-signal safe.

You only need one global `pthread_mutex_t` to avoid the case where the kernel hands the recently-moved hole (`mremap()`ped from memory area) to another thread; you can also use it to protect your internal data structure (pointer chain, if you support multiple concurrent file mappings).

There should be no race conditions (other than when other threads use `mmap()` or `mremap()`, which is handled by the mutex mentioned above). When a "dirty" page or page group is moved away, it becomes inaccessible to other threads, before it is converted and saved; even perfectly concurrent access by another thread should be handled perfectly: the page will simply be re-read from the file, and re-converted. (If that occurs often, you might wish to cache recently saved page groups.)

I do recommend using large page groups, say 2M or more, instead of single pages, to reduce the overhead. The optimal size depends on your applications access patterns, but the huge page size (if supported by your architecture) is a very good starting point.

If your data structures do not align to pages or page groups, you should cache the full converted first and last records (which are only partially within the page or page group). It usually makes the conversion back to storage format much easier.

If you know or can detect typical access patterns within the file, you probably should use `posix_fadvise()` to tell the kernel; `POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED` and `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` are most useful. It helps the kernel avoid keeping unnecessary pages of the actual data file in page cache.

Finally, you might consider adding a second special thread for converting and writing dirty records back to disk asynchronously. If you take care to make sure the two threads don't get confused when the first thread wants to re-read back a record still being written to disk by the second thread, there should be no other issues there either -- but asynchronous writing is likely to increase your throughput with most access patterns, unless you are I/O bound anyway, or really short on RAM (relatively speaking).

Why use `read()` and `write()` instead of another memory map? Because of the overhead in-kernel for the virtual memory structures needed.