# About catching the SIGSEGV in multithreaded environment

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'd like to know if it is possible/the recommended way to catch the `SIGSEGV` signal in multithreaded environment. I am particularly interested in handling the `SIGSEGV` raised by something like `*((int *)0) = 0`.

Some reading on this topic led me to `signal()` and `sigaction()`, which install a signal handler. While neither seem promising in multithreaded environment. I then tried the `sigwaitinfo()`, receiving the signals in one thread with a prior `pthread_sigmask()` call that blocks the signal on the others. It worked to the extent upon which the signal `SIGSEGV` was raised, using raise(), inside a thread or when it was sent to the process by something like `kill -SIGSEGV`; however, `\*((int*)0) = 0` still kills the process. My test program is as follows

```
void block_signal()
{
        sigset_t set;

        sigemptyset(&set);
        sigaddset(&set, SIGSEGV);
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);

        if (pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "pthread_sigmask failed\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

void *buggy_thread(void *param)
{
        char *ptr = NULL;
        block_signal();

        printf("Thread %lu created\n", pthread_self());

        // Sleep for some random time
        { ... }

        printf("About to raise from %lu\n", pthread_self());

        // Raise a SIGSEGV
        *ptr = 0;

        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *dispatcher(void *param)
{
        sigset_t set;
        siginfo_t info;
        int sig;

        sigemptyset(&set);
        sigaddset(&set, SIGSEGV);

        for (;;) {
                sig = sigwaitinfo(&set, &info);
                if (sig == -1)
                        fprintf(stderr, "sigwaitinfo failed\n");
                else
                        printf("Received signal SIGSEGV from %u\n", info.si_pid);
        }
}

int main()
{
        int i;
        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_t disp_tid;

        block_signal();

        if (pthread_create(&disp_tid, NULL, dispatcher, NULL)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create dispatcher\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, buggy_thread, NULL) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create thread\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }

        pause();
}
```

Unexpectedly, the program dies with a segmentation fault instead of printing the raiser's thread id.

Comment: Why do you want to catch `SIGSEGV` ? What will you do after having caught it?

Answer (score 10):

Your code does not call [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), and I believe it should call it. Read also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). And the signal action (thru `sa_sigaction` field should do something (machine specific) with its `siginfo_t` to skip the offending machine instruction, or to `mmap` the offending address, or call `siglongjmp`, otherwise when returning from the signal handler you'll get the `SIGSEGV` again since the offending machine instruction is restarted.

You cannot handle the `SIGSEGV` in another thread, since synchronous signals (such as `SIGSEGV` or `SIGSYS`) are thread specific (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6533431/841108)), so what you try to achieve with `sigwaitinfo` cannot work. In particular **`SIGSEGV` is directed to the offending thread**.

Read also [all about Linux signals](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals).

PS. An example of clever `SIGSEGV` handling is offered by the no-more maintained (in May 2019) [Ravenbrook MPS](https://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/) garbage collector library. Notice also the Linux specific and recent [userfaultfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/userfaultfd.2.html) and [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) system calls.

Comment: Signal disposition is not thread-local. Only signal mask, and in some cases signal delivery, is thread-local.

Comment: Thanks for the resourceful references. But when I replaced the offending line '*ptr = 0' with 'raise(SIGSEGV)', then the above code worked. Don't know why '*ptr = 0' doesn't produce the same result.

Comment: Because segentation violation like `*ptr = 0;` are thread specific, so the `SIGSEGV` is sent to the offending thread. This is not the same with `raise(SIGSEGV)`

Comment: Actually no, raise() can also sends a signal to the calling thread. In a multithreaded program raise(sig) is equivalent to pthread_kill(pthread_self(), sig). Refer to the manpage.

Answer (score 8):

Signal delivery for `SIGSEGV` caused by a faulting memory access is to the thread that performed the invalid access. Per POSIX ([XSH 2.4.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_01)):

> At the time of generation, a determination shall be made whether the signal has been generated for the process or for a specific thread within the process. Signals which are generated by some action attributable to a particular thread, such as a hardware fault, shall be generated for the thread that caused the signal to be generated. Signals that are generated in association with a process ID or process group ID or an asynchronous event, such as terminal activity, shall be generated for the process.

The problematic aspect of trying to handle `SIGSEGV` in a multi-threaded program is that, while delivery and signal mask are thread-local, the signal *disposition* (i.e. what handler to call) is process-global. In other words, `sigaction` sets a signal handler for the whole process, not just the calling thread. This means that multiple threads each trying to setup their own `SIGSEGV` handlers will clobber each other's settings.

The best solution I can propose is to set a global signal handler for `SIGSEGV` using `sigaction`, preferably with `SA_SIGINFO` so you get additional information about the fault, then have a thread-local variable for a handler for the specific thread. Then, the actual signal handler can be:

```
_Thread_local void (*thread_local_sigsegv_handler)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
static void sigsegv_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *ctx)
{
    thread_local_sigsegv_handler(sig, si, ctx);
}
```

Note that this makes use of C11 thread-local storage. If you don't have that available, you can fall back to either "GNU C" `__thread` thread-local storage, or POSIX thread-specific data (using `pthread_key_create` and `pthread_setspecific`/`pthread_getspecific`). Strictly speaking, the latter are not async-signal-safe, so calling them from the signal handler invokes UB if the illegal access took place inside a non-async-signal-safe function in the standard library. However, if it took place in your own code, you can be sure no non-async-signal-safe function was interrupted by the signal handler, and thus these functions have well-defined behavior (well, modulo the fact that your whole program probably already has UB from whatever it did to generate `SIGSEGV`...).

Comment: i did not quite understand what is the profit gained from having thread_local_sigsegv_handler. if i understood correctly, this is a global function pointer (allocated specifically for each thread). But how do you get the thread that caused the signal to be raise to call that function?

Comment: That always happens for synchronously-generated signals. See XSH 2.4.1 *Signal Generation and Delivery*: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_01: *At the time of generation, a determination shall be made whether the signal has been generated for the process or for a specific thread within the process. Signals which are generated by some action attributable to a particular thread, such as a hardware fault, shall be generated for the thread that caused the signal to be generated.*

Comment: According to https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Thread_002dspecific-Data.html pthread_getspecific is async signal safe (pthread_setspecific is not), so using POSIX thread-specific data storage should be fine (at least with glibc). On the other hand, I could not find any information regardings whether variables declared __thread (or thread_local in C++ 11) are actually async signal safe. Any link to thedocumentation regarding this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

"Why do you want to catch SIGSEGV ? What will you do after having caught it?"

The most common answer would be: quit/abort. But then, what would be the reason to even deliver this signal to a process instead of just arbitrarily terminating it?

The answer is: because signals, including the SIGSEGV, are just exceptions - and it's very important for some applications to f.e. set the hardware outputs to a "safe mode" or make sure that some important data is left in consistent state before terminating the process.

There are generally 2 kinds of segfaults: caused by write or by read operations.

Segfaults caused by **read** operations are perfectly safe to catch and even to ignore in some cases(1). Failed **write** operations need more attention and effort to be safely processed (risk of data/memory corruption), but this is also possible (f.e. by avoiding to dynamically allocate the memory after a segfault).

The problem with "critical signals" (which are delivered to a particular thread, like SIGFPE or SIGSEGV) is that normally the program don't "know" what is the context of the signal - that is, which operation or function have triggered the signal.

There are at least few possible ways to get those informations, for example:

1. Each thread can perform only a single class of small operations - so if it gets a signal, then it's easy to tell what happened -> terminate the thread, verify the processed data, etc. -> terminate safely.
2. Use **C exceptions** - there are few ready to use solutions, mine is: [libcxc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libcxc/)

(1) F.e. the famous problem with ESRCH and pthread_kill() issued for a thread which have already exited on its own :)

Comment: "Why do you want to catch SIGSEGV ? What will you do after having caught it?"
To postpone the whole process termination before other threads finish their current part of the job (which could be important for the logic of the program). I do not see why if one thread accessed foreign memory all the other must unconditionally die at the same time, especially if it does not affect the state of the whole process except that one thread.