# Catching signals such as SIGSEGV and SIGFPE in multithreaded program

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, posix

I am trying to write a multithreaded logging system for a program running on linux.

Calls to the logging system in the main program threads pushes a data structure containing the data to be logged into a FIFO queue. A dedicated thread picks the data of the queue and outputs the data, while the programs main thread continues with its task.

If the main program causes SIGSEGV or other signals to be raised I need to make sure that the queue is empty before terminating.

My plan is to block the signals using pthread_sigmask http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html for all but one thread, but reading the list of signals on http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html i noticed:

> *A signal may be generated (and thus pending) for a process as a whole (e.g., when sent >using kill(2)) or for a specific thread (e.g., certain signals, such as SIGSEGV and SIGFPE, >generated as a consequence of executing a specific machine-language instruction are
>   thread directed, as are signals targeted at a specific thread using pthread_kill(3)).*

If I block SIGSEGV on all threads but a thread dedicated to catching signals, will it then catch a SIGSEGV raised by a different thread?

I found the question [Signal handling with multiple threads in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679568/signal-handling-with-multiple-threads-in-linux), but I am clueless as to which signals are thread specific and how to catch them.

Comment: It's been my view for about thirty years that programs shouldn't catch SIGSEGV: they should be debugged.

Comment: I Agree. The whole purpose of catching SIGSEGV or similar systems is to get the last logged info out the program, to help find the bug that caused the program to fail in the first place.

Comment: So temporarily disable buffering in the log system, run the program, check the log, debug the program.

Comment: Did you try to wait for the logger;s queue to become empty in the signal handler and then continue with normal operation? Justa questions, don't know if that's possible.

Comment: Continuing the normal flow of the program sounds dangerous to me. The program is in a state it really shouldn't be in.

Comment: The program should abort ASAP, but first outputting the leftover logging messages in the queue.
If "normal operation" implies returning from the signal handler to continue the thread that caused the signal, I can't imagine how I can stay out of undefined behaviour.
Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: If your program is throwing SIGSEGV (or SSIGBUS) then you are up a certain creek without a certain instrument. I think it is game over

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with the comments: in practice catching and handling `SIGSEGV` is often a bad thing.

And `SIGSEGV` is delivered to a *specific* thread (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6533431/841108)), the one running the machine instruction which accessed to some illegal address.

So you cannot run a thread dedicated to catching `SIGSEGV` in other threads. And you probably could not easily use [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) for `SIGSEGV`...

Catching (and returning normally from its signal handler) `SIGSEGV` is a complex and *processor specific* thing (it cannot be "portable C code"). You need to inspect and alter the machine state in the handler, that is either modify the address space (by calling [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) etc...) or modify the register state of the current thread. So use [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) with `SA_SIGINFO` and change the machine specific state pointed by the third argument (of type `ucontext_t*`) of the signal handler. Then dive into the *processor specific* `uc_mcontext` field of it. Have fun changing individual registers, etc... If you don't alter the machine state of the faulty thread, execution is resumed (after returning from your `SIGSEGV` handler) in the same situation as before, and another `SIGSEGV` signal is immediately sent.... Or simply, don't return normally from a `SIGSEGV` handler (e.g. use [siglongjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/siglongjmp.3.html) or [abort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html) or [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) ...).

Even if you happen to do all this, it is rumored that Linux kernels are not extremely efficient on such executions. So it is rumored that trying to mimic Hurd/Mach external pagers this way on Linux is not very efficient. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11681530/841108)...

Of course signal handlers should call only (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for more) async-signal-safe functions. In particular, you cannot in principle call `fprintf` from them (and you might not be able to use *reliably* your logging system, but it could work in most but not all cases).

What I said on `SIGSEGV` also holds for `SIGBUS` and `SIGFPE` (and other thread-specific asynchronous signals, if they exist).

Comment: If specifically protecting an area of memory from thread access for a certain amount of time with mprotect(), a SIGSEGV handler can indeed be portable, because subsequent SEGVs will not be "random invalid memory access" that need complex fixup.  Of course, one should check that the faulting address is indeed in the protected range, and if not, abort the program, because the SEGV was from an invalid access in that case.