# How Limit memory usage for a single Linux process and not kill the process

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How Limit memory usage for a single Linux process and not kill the process.

I know ulimit can limit memory usage, but if exceed the limit, will kill the process.

Is there any other command or shell can limit memory usage and not kill the process?

Comment: `> but if exceed the limit, will kill the process. `. This is not correct. In this case malloc() (in case C application) simply returns NULL and your process is not killed. It is probably killed because of attepts to do something with NULL pointer. http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc -- On error, these functions return NULL.

Answer (score 7):

Another way besides  [setrlimit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html), which can be set using the ulimit utility:

$ ulimit -Sv 500000     # Set ~500 mb limit

is to use [Linux's control groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups), because it limits a process's (or group of processes') allocation of physical memory distinctly from virtual memory.  For example:

> $ cgcreate -g memory:/myGroup
>   $ echo $(( 500 * 1024 * 1024 )) > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/myGroup/memory.limit_in_bytes
>   $ echo $(( 5000 * 1024 * 1024 )) > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/myGroupmemory.memsw.limit_in_bytes

will create a control group named "myGroup", cap the set of processes run under myGroup up to 500 MB of physical memory and up to 5000 MB of swap.  To run a process under the control group:

> $ cgexec -g memory:myGroup COMMAND

**Note:** For what I can understand setrlimit will limit the virtual memory, although with cgroups you can limit the physical memory.

Comment: Interesting, but I guess that if resources are exhausted, the process still will be killed.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are wrong on thinking that a limit set with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) will always kill the process.

Indeed, if the stack space is exceeded (`RLIMIT_STACK`), the process would be killed (with `SIGSEGV`).

But if it is heap memory (`RLIMIT_DATA` or `RLIMIT_AS`), [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) would fail. If it has been called from [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/malloc.3.html) or friends, that `malloc` would fail.

<sup>Some Linux systems are configured with [memory overcommit](http://opsmonkey.blogspot.fr/2007/01/linux-memory-overcommit.html). 
 This is a sysadmin issue: `echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`</sup>

The moral of the story is that you should *always* check result of `malloc`, at least like

```
struct mystruct_st *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct_st));
if (!ptr) { perror("mystruct allocation"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

<sup>Of course, sophisticated applications could handle "out-of-memory" conditions more wisely, but it is difficult to get right.</sup>

Some people incorrectly assumes that `malloc` does not fail (this is wrong). But that is their mistake. Then they dereference a `NULL` pointer, getting a `SIGSEGV` that they deserve.

You could consider catching `SIGSEGV` with some *processor-specific* code, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20310127/841108). Unless you are a guru, don't do that.

Comment: Exiting when `malloc` returns `NULL` is hardly different from crashing from user's perspective. And I believe that most programs don't crash, just exit as soon as `malloc` fail.

Comment: I disagree, there is an error message given by `perror` and that is a difference the user will understand. BTW, sophisticated applications might handle `malloc` failure in a much wiser way....