# Why can't capture SIGSEGV using signalfd?

Tags: linux, signals

My system is ubuntu 12.04.
I modify the example from `man 2 signalfd`, and add `sigaddset(&mask, SIGSEGV)` in the exmaple. But I can't get the output when `SIGSEGV` is generated.

Is it a bug of `glibc`? The fragment of source code is following:

```
       sigemptyset(&mask);
       sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT);
       sigaddset(&mask, SIGQUIT);
       sigaddset(&mask, SIGSEGV);

       /* Block signals so that they aren't handled
          according to their default dispositions */

       if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1)
           handle_error("sigprocmask");

       sfd = signalfd(-1, &mask, 0);
       if (sfd == -1)
           handle_error("signalfd");
        int* a = NULL;
       for (;;) {
           s = read(sfd, &fdsi, sizeof(struct signalfd_siginfo));
           if (s != sizeof(struct signalfd_siginfo))
               handle_error("read");

           if (fdsi.ssi_signo == SIGINT) {
               printf("Got SIGINT\n");
               (*a) = 1;
           } else if (fdsi.ssi_signo == SIGQUIT) {
               printf("Got SIGQUIT\n");
               exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
           } else {
               printf("Read unexpected signal\n");
           }
       }
```

Comment: Please explain why you want to catch `SIGSEGV` ....

Comment: I just want to test whether "SIGSEGV" can be handled asynchronously and output stack backtrace information. Because there are many "unsafe function" which can't be used in signal handler.

Comment: As I added in my answer, for backtrace purposes you could afford using unsafe functions from a `SIGSEGV` handler. This often works well (but might fail or crash)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16204696/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6533431/841108) answers for detailed explanations. Read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Remember also that the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) is common to, and shared between, all the [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) of that process. See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) (and use [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html)) and try reading `/proc/self/maps`  from inside your process to understand its actual virtual address space.

Grossly speaking, if you handle (an asynchronous) `SIGSEGV` (produced by the kernel after some exception fault) with [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html), it is looking like you installed a "kernel" signal handler which magically "write"-s some bytes on some file descriptor (you almost could mimick `signalfd` by installing a signal handler writing on some pipe; but `signalfd` guarantees some "atomicity" that you won't have otherwise).

When you are back from that handling, the machine is in the same condition, so the SIGSEGV happens again.

If you want to handle `SIGSEGV` you need to use [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) or the obsolete `signal(2)` to install a handling routine (so you can't use `signalfd` for SIGSEGV), and then you should either

- (more or less portably) avoid returning from your signal handler (e.g. by calling [siglongjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/siglongjmp.3.html) from your signal handler installed with [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html))
- non-portably (in a processor and operating system specific way) change the machine context (given by the third argument (a pointer to some processor specific `ucontext_t`) to your handler installed by `sigaction` with `SA_SIGINFO`), e.g. by changing some registers, or change the address space (e.g. by calling [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) from inside the handler).

The insight is that a SIGSEGV handler is entered with the program counter set to the faulting machine instruction. When you return from a SIGSEGV handler, the registers are in the state given to it (the pointer `ucontext_t` as the third argument of your `sa_sigaction` function passed to `sigaction`). If you don't change that state, the same machine instruction is re-executed, and since you didn't change anything the same fault happens and the same SIGSEGV signal is sent again by the kernel.

BTW, a nice example of a software handling cleverly and non-portably the SIGSEGV is the [Ravenbrook MPS](https://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps) garbage collection library. Their write barrier (in GC parlance) is implemented by handling SIGSEGV. This is very clever (and non portable) code.

NB: in practice, if you just want to display backtrace information, you could do it from a `SIGSEGV` handler (e.g. by using [GCC libbacktrace](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/tree/master/libbacktrace) or [backtrace(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) then [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html)-ing instead of returning from your `SIGSEGV` signal handler); it is not perfect and won't always work -e.g. if you [corrupted the memory heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption)- because you will call non async-signal-safe functions, but in practice works well enough. Recent GCC is doing that (inside the compiler e.g. `cc1plus` and its plugins), and it helps a lot.

Comment: Thanks. if "SIGSEGV" generated by *a =1 isn't in local-thread, which thread does "SIGSEGV" belong to?

Comment: There is always one thread (so called the main thread) or "task" in a single-threaded process.

Answer (score 3):

You can only block a `SIGSEGV` sent by `kill(2)` and friends. From the manpage of `sigprocmask(2)`:

> If SIGBUS, SIGFPE, SIGILL, or SIGSEGV are generated while they are
> blocked, the result is undefined, unless the signal was generated by
> kill(2), sigqueue(3), or raise(3)

---

Since the signal isn't really blocked by `sigprocmask` - a prerequisite of `signalfd` - `signalfd` doesn't work. A simple way to test is to use your program but instead of causing a true segmentation fault, send a signal with `kill -11`.

Comment: But `signalfd` is not *blocking* a signal, so that does not really answer the question...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Good call. I edited my answer to explain that the quote is from `sigprocmask`.