# Can C language decide if a memory pointed by pointer can be accessed?

Tags: c, pointers

Example.

If I have a pointer,

```
int* p;
p = (int*)2; // just for test
*p = 3; // it will be crack, right?
```

In general, the access of the pointer of value 2 will be crack. But actually the crack is not so simple. Invalid value of the pointer maybe comes from the Runtime error. I'd like to find a way to check the pointer before accessing it.

Comment: There's no way to check if a pointer is valid in C. Accessing invalid memory is also not guarenteed to throw an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In standard C99, this (dereferencing `(int*)2`  in your `*p =3;` statement) is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB). Read [C.Lattner's blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) on that. You should [be *very scared* of UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636753/is-segmentation-fault-actual-undefined-behavior-when-we-refer-to-a-non-static-da/25636788#25636788). This is why programming in C is so hard (other programming languages like Ocaml, Common Lisp have much less UB).

<sup>A C program may have undefined behavior but might not always crash.</sup>

In practice, when coding in C, be vary careful about pointers. Initialize all of them explicitly (often to `NULL`). Be very careful about pointer arithmetic. Avoid [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). [Static source code analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) may help (e.g. with [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/)) but is limited (read about [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) & [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)). You could use quite often [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) and check pointers and indexes at runtime.

On some embedded freestanding C implementations (e.g. coding for [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) like devices), some addresses might have particular meanings (e.g. be some physical IO devices), hence UB could be *very* scary.

<sup>(I am focusing on Linux below)</sup>

On some implementations, and some operating systems, you might test if an address is valid. For example on Linux you might parse `/proc/self/maps` to compute if some given address is valid (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more about `/proc/`).

<sup>(therefore, you could write -on Linux- some function `bool isreadableaddress(void*)`  which would parse `/proc/self/maps` and tell if an address is readable in the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29); but it won't be very efficient since needing several [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call))</sup>

And you should use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and compile with all warnings & debug options (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and use the debugger (`gdb`) and some more [debugging compiler options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) like `-fsanitize=address`

You might perhaps handle the `SIGSEGV`  signal, but [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21204438/841108) is *very tricky* and highly non-portable (operating system, processor, and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific). Unless you are a guru, you should not even try.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking about whether the pointer can be checked, though.

Comment: Beware that on Windows there are functions that appear to do exactly what the OP wants (IsBadReadPtr etc).  Do not use them: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563/  (Title is "IsBadXXXPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly")  .There *may* be somebody who knows more about Windows than the author of that article, but I wouldn't want to bet on it.  Every windows programmer should read the blog.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "it will be crack".

Your program has no way to know whether an arbitrarily-initialised pointer will practically "work" at runtime. Firstly, you compile your code before you run it, potentially on a completely different computer. The compiler cannot predict the future.

The language deals with this by saying *any* pointer not explicitly made to point to *an object or array that you created in the program* cannot exist as long as you want your program to have well-defined behaviour.

**Basically, the only way to be sure is to *not do this*.**

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible... sort of....

Not with plain C, but most environments allow you to test whether a you can write to a pointer...

[for example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366716(v=vs.85).aspx)

Unfortunately you have no way of knowing if a pointer points at what **you intend**. Meaning you can be pointing at another valid address, different from what you expect, and unintentionally corrupt a piece of your own memory...

```
char a[2];
int b; // assuming they are stored on the stack sequentially and aligned one right after the other...

char *ptr = (char*)a;

ptr += 3;

*ptr = 'b' // valid pointer, but probably an error....
```

Comment: How does that answer the question of dereferencing `(int*)2` ? Also, Martin Bonner commented (my answer) and cite https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563/ which basically discourage using `IsBadWritePtr`  on Windows...

Comment: have you read the title of his post? he doesn't care about `(int*)2` ... it's just an example... I tried to explain, in simple terms, why what he is asking for is essentially impossible.

Comment: On Linux, it is possible (thru `/proc/self/maps`) to tell if a given address is readable. But your argument applies. A valid address might not point to something intended.

Comment: Cool :-) . some more characters

Comment: `*ptr = 'b'` is not a *valid pointer*.  It may crash or not crash. for example `a` could be just before the return address on the stack, of if you execute under valgrind, it may stop the program.

Comment: Please read the answer again... For the sake of the example, I assume that, at that line 'ptr' will point to an address where 'b' is