# Detect every memory accesses made by a C/C++ program

Tags: c, memory, trace, heap-memory

I am trying to detect every access programs written in C/C++ is making while running, in particular to dynamically allocated memory. In addition, I would like to have some information about where the access was made. The function name that made the access is what I am looking for.

For example, for the following code:

```
void MemoryAccess(int* my_vector) {
    int x = my_vector[0]; // Read access from 0xFFFF0000.
    my_vector[0] = x + 1; // Write access to 0XFFFF0000.
}

int main(void) {
    // Assume that the address returned by malloc is 0xFFFF0000.
    int* vec = malloc(VEC_SIZE * sizeof(int));
    if (!vec) {
        return MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAIL;
    }
    MemoryAccess(vec);

    int second_elem = vec[1]; // Read access from 0xFFFF0004.
    v[1] = 10; // Write access to 0xFFFF0004.

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to record a log file, containing the following: address that have been accessed, the function name that made the access. For the above example, my log should look something like:

```
{Read}  {MemoryAccess} {0xFFFF0000}
{Write} {MemoryAccess} {0xFFFF0000}
{Read}  {main}         {0xFFFF0004}
{Write} {main}         {0xFFFF0004}
```

I have been able to do something like this on Windows using Exception Filter and modify the page protection of the monitored memory block. I couldn't get the function name that made the access, only Instruction Pointer value when the exception was raised and I couldn't figure how to use that to get the function name.

Note: My goal is to monitor memory access on a Linux based system (Debian/Ubuntu mostly), not Windows.

Comment: Could valgrind help you?

Comment: Please provide a link to the specification of that "C/C++" language. until then there are only the two **different** languages C and C++. This is not C++. There are like different solutions for your problem in both languages.

Comment: @Angew: I don't think Valgrind will monitor **every** access.

Comment: Please **give your motivations** so **edit your question** to improve it a big lot.

Comment: Do you care about one particular program (which one?) or are you ambitious enough to seek a more generic solution? Then why do you ask?

Comment: Question is "by a C/C++ program".  Post says "program written in C++" and post is tagged `C`.  So it is unclear what language an answer should use.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch For the moment I am trying to monitor the functions that read/write a chunk of memory, so I can understand better what happens with that data inside a function (maybe one function just read from memory, other may only write to memory, or both).

Comment: @FlorinAvram: if you are struggling with one particular software, you just need GDB watchpoints & `valgrind`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What I trying to do is similar with what GDB does, but I just want to log access made to a memory zone, applying different test cases to it and then analyze the logs to observe some patterns. That is the main reason why I need those log files.

Comment: But **why do you need this?**, how generic do you want the solution to be, do you accept it to be *very* slow,  and how many many years can you invest in implementing it ? What is the software on which you want such instrumentation? Are you willing to spend a dozen of years of work? So please **edit your question** (or ask a much more focused one, explaining much more and giving a lot of details and of source code)

Comment: 1. How generic do you want the solution to be?
I want to create a simple API, that let's me modify the source code of a program, recompile it, run a suite of test cases and the have the logs for a chunk of memory that I have selected. For example, if in my source code I will have something like char* buff = malloc(100), free(buff). I want to add a piece of code after malloc that will start monitoring this memory, and one before free, to unmonitor the memory.

Comment: That should go in your question, not in comments. And do you want some generic solution, or simply something for one particular program? I guess using GCC MELT should fit quite well. But your goals are quite ambitious, even if you limit them to your above example.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>(I am focusing on Linux)</sup>

What you want to do will be *very slow* and need *unportable code* if done naively. I am supposing that you want a generic solution (working on many C++ programs, not on some particular one).

You could patch some emulator, à la Qemu.

Maybe you just want to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or [GCC debugging options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) like address sanitizer (search for `-fsanitize=address`). Or use **`gdb` watchpoints**. Notice that recent GDB are scriptable in Python or Guile.

Maybe you could take inspiration from `valgrind`tricks.

Look also into [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)

If you don't want disastrous performance (that is, naively interpreting each machine instruction and/or handling a SIGSEGV for every memory access, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21204438/841108) for more) you need to be tricky.

You could consider customizing the GCC compiler (e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) so that some (relevant) loads & stores get instrumented inside the compiler.

If you take a naive approach (sort of interpreting every machine instruction and/or crude SIGSEGV handling), you'll probably slow your program by more than a factor of thousand, and that "semi-naive" approach still needs months of work. And you'll encounter [Heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

If you want a serious approach, you'll need to modify your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) so that some instrumentation code is *additionally* emitted by the compiler, recompile the program to be instrumented (and all the libraries it is using) and that could probably take you at least a year (unless you are already fluent with GCC internals).

If you are serious, study more computer science ([computer architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture), [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)), and make your PhD working on that. You'll need several years of hard work.