# Trying to cause a segmentation fault with mmap

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, mmap

Just to understand how things work, I am trying to allocate some memory from the kernel with `mmap` and then set the protection bits such that any memory access causes a segmentation fault,  after that I want to try and set the protection bits to be such that the segmentation fault does not happen again.

The call to mprotect fails, and the address in `si_addr` is wrong even though the linux man page for `sigaction` says that the `siginfo` struct's `si_addr` function contains the address that causes the fault.  And the address is not the address that was allocated in the `main()` function.  *The code works fine on a mac*

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

void handle_signal(int signal_number, siginfo_t* signal_info, void* context);
void register_signal_handler();

int counter = 0;

int main() {
    register_signal_handler();
    int* page_mapped = (int*) mmap(nullptr, 100, PROT_NONE,
            MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
    if (page_mapped == MAP_FAILED) {
        cerr << "mmap failed" << endl;
    }
    cout << "page mapped is " << reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(page_mapped)
         << endl;

    // cause the segmentation fault
    cout << *page_mapped << endl;

    return 0;
}

void handle_signal(int, siginfo_t* siginfo, void*) {
    cout << "Handled a segmentation fault" << endl;
    cout << "The segmentation fault was caused by the address "
         << reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(siginfo->si_addr) << endl;
    if (mprotect(siginfo->si_addr, 100, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE) == -1) {
        cerr << "mprotect failed" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // stop an infinite loop
    ++counter;
    if (counter == 3) {
        cerr << "Counter got to 3, probably going into an infinite loop.. "
            "stopping" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

void register_signal_handler() {
    struct sigaction sigaction_information;
    memset(&sigaction_information, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sigaction_information.sa_sigaction = &handle_signal;
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sigaction_information, nullptr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21204438/841108). It explains that a `SIGSEGV` signal handler should *change* the machine state, otherwise the same *machine instruction* is restarted and gives some exception that the kernel translates into the *same* signal being sent (in the same "context"), hence the loop.

BTW, using C++ I/O (or even `<stdio.h>`) inside a signal handler is wrong (because you are then using non-async signal safe functions). Read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Be aware that a signal handler is forbidden to call many functions (those which are not the async-signal-safe ones).

And your call to [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) is wrong (and failing). The size should be a multiple of the page size (typically 4K) and the address should also be a multiple of it (you probably should use `page_mapped`, not `siginfo->si_addr`, as the address argument to `mprotect`; alternatively you might round *down* `siginfo->si_addr` to the previous multiple of the 4K pagesize). When I run your program (compiled by `g++ -O -Wall curious.cc -o curious` on Debian/x86-64 with GCC 6 & linux kernel 4.8) it complains: `mprotect failed` (with `EINVAL` error, given by [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html)).

You could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand more exactly what is happening.

At last, your `counter` should be declared as [`volatile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_%28computer_programming%29).

By declaring both `counter` and `page_mapped` as volatile *global* variables:

```
volatile int counter;
int*volatile page_mapped;
```

and by having inside `handle_signal` the following code (on my system, page size is 4K):

```
if (mprotect(page_mapped, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE) == -1) {
  /// this is still wrong in theory, 
  /// .... since we are using non-async signal safe functions
  perror("mprotect");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  /// but in practice mprotect is successful
}
```

it behaves differently (and a bit more like you wish) because `mprotect` is not failing and the final value of `counter` (at end of `main`) is 1 (as you want it to be).

Comment: *a SIGSEGV signal handler should change the machine state* Why is this necessary if the signal handler removes the protection from the page that caused the segfault (and therefore restarting the same machine instruction should not reraise the same signal)?

Comment: Changing the protection is changing the machine state (e.g. in MMU).

Comment: So how do I get mprotect to properly protect the address that caused the segmentation fault?

Comment: This code seems to work fine on my mac but no longer works on a linux machine

Answer (score 0):

You missed this from [`man sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) only:

> If **SA_SIGINFO** is specified in *sa_flags*, then *sa_sigaction* (instead of
>          *sa_handler*) specifies the signal-handling function for *signum*.

In other words, if you want to specify *sa_sigaction* instead of
       *sa_handler*, you must set that flag, so

```
    sigaction_information.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
```

is to be added in `register_signal_handler()`.